# rendering results of multiple DB/mongoose queries to a view in express.js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

given the async nature of mongoose (or sequelize, or redis) queries, what do you do when you have multiple queries you need to make before rendering the view?

For instance, you have a `user_id` in a session, and want to retrieve some info about that particular user via `findOne`. But you also want to display a list of recently logged in users.

```
exports.index = function (req, res) {
    var current_user = null

    Player.find({last_logged_in : today()}).exec(function(err, players) {
        if (err) return res.render('500');

        if (req.session.user_id) {
            Player.findOne({_id : req.session.user_id}).exec(function(err, player) {
                if (err) return;
                if (player) {
                    current_user = player
                }
            })
        }

        // here, current_user isn't populated until the callback fires 
        res.render('game/index', { title: 'Battle!',
                   players: players,
                   game_is_full: (players.length >= 6),
                   current_user: current_user
        });
    });
};
```

So `res.render` is in the first query callback, fine. But what about waiting on the response from `findOne` to see if we know this user? It is only called conditionally, so I can't put `render` inside the inner callback, unless I duplicate it for either condition. Not pretty.

I can think of some workarounds -

- make it *really* async and use AJAX on the client side to get the current user's profile. But this seems like more work than it's worth.
- use `Q` and promises to wait on the resolution of the `findOne` query before rendering. But in a way, this would be like forcing blocking to make the response wait on my operation. Doesn't seem right.
- use a middleware function to get the current user info. This seems cleaner, makes the query reusable. However I'm not sure how to go about it or if it would still manifest the same problem.

Of course, in a more extreme case, if you have a dozen queries to make, things might get ugly. So, what is the usual pattern given this type of requirement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, this is a particularly annoying case in async code.  What you can do is to put the code you'd have to duplicate into a local function to keep it DRY:

```
exports.index = function (req, res) {
    var current_user = null

    Player.find({last_logged_in : today()}).exec(function(err, players) {
        if (err) return res.render('500');

        function render() {
            res.render('game/index', { title: 'Battle!',
                       players: players,
                       game_is_full: (players.length >= 6),
                       current_user: current_user
            });
        }

        if (req.session.user_id) {
            Player.findOne({_id : req.session.user_id}).exec(function(err, player) {
                if (err) return;
                if (player) {
                    current_user = player
                }
                render();
            })
        } else {
            render();
        }
    });
};
```

However, looking at what you're doing here, you'll probably need to look up the current player information in multiple request handlers, so in that case you're better off using middleware.

Something like:

```
exports.loadUser = function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.session.user_id) {
        Player.findOne({_id : req.session.user_id}).exec(function(err, player) {
            if (err) return;
            if (player) {
                req.player = player
            }
            next();
        })
    } else {
        next();
    }
}
```

Then you'd configure your routes to call `loadUser` wherever you need `req.player` populated and the route handler can just pull the player details right from there.

Comment: thanks, seems simple enough. What about using `async.parallel` to pull all the results together? I tried it and it seems to work, but wonder if it's a good approach. Yours is a lot less obfuscated, for sure.

Comment: Yeah `async.parallel` doesn't work well here.  I updated my answer to include a middleware solution that's probably a better fit for your use case.

Comment: nice, that's reusable and cleaner thanks to chaining with `next()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
router.get("/",function(req,res){
    var locals = {};
    var userId = req.params.userId;
    async.parallel([
        //Load user Data
        function(callback) {
             mongoOp.User.find({},function(err,user){
                if (err) return callback(err);
                locals.user = user;
                callback();
            });
        },
        //Load posts Data
        function(callback) {
                mongoOp.Post.find({},function(err,posts){
               if (err) return callback(err);
                locals.posts = posts;
                callback();
            });
        }
    ], function(err) { //This function gets called after the two tasks have called their "task callbacks"
        if (err) return next(err); //If an error occurred, we let express handle it by calling the `next` function
        //Here `locals` will be an object with `user` and `posts` keys
        //Example: `locals = {user: ..., posts: [...]}`
         res.render('index.ejs', {userdata: locals.user,postdata: locals.posts})
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can use app.param in ExpressJS to easily establish middleware that loads needed data based on the name of parameters in the request URL.

http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.param