# Two database queries in Mongoose with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

There are a lot instances where I have to make two database queries that depend on each other .. But because of the asynchronous nature of js, I can't set the order of these query requests. The work around I have been using is put one of the queries in the callback of the other one. My approach seems like its working but I just want to know if there are better ways of doing this?

example code:

```
app.get('/tweet', function(req,res){

  User.findOne({ twitterID: req.user.id },
    function(err, user) { 
        if (user){
             var votedPosts = user.votedPosts;
                Post.find(function (err, posts) {
                    if(posts){
                    for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++){
                        for (var j = 0; j < votedPosts.length; j++){
                          if(votedPosts[j]._id == posts[i]._id){
                            posts[i].votetype = votedPosts[j].votetype;
                          }
                          else{
                            console.log("this is getting called");
                            posts[i].votetype = 0;
                          }
                        }
                    }
                    res.send(posts);
                  }
                });
          }
    });
});
```

Comment: Duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243507/rendering-results-of-multiple-db-mongoose-queries-to-a-view-in-express-js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are many many flow control libraries to solve the deeply nested callback problem. I recommend [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) or [nimble](https://github.com/caolan/nimble), but [promises](http://howtonode.org/promises) is another popular pattern that solves this problem.

The basic progression as you add code and it gets longer and more deeply nested over time is:

- deal with 1 or 2 nesting levels with small amounts of code. It's not that bad.
- Extract things to top-level named functions and call them (most node.js core code tries not to get beyond this point)
- use a library (either custom API or based on the promises pattern)

There is a [long list of flow control modules](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Modules#wiki-async-flow) on the node wiki. You could also [search](https://npmjs.org/search?q=async) [npm](https://npmjs.org/search?q=flow)